# IBM MQ copy every 5th message to another queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a queue with a huge message throughput. I would like to create new queue for lower environments. This new queue shouldn't be a 1-to-1 copy since it is going to cost too much. I would like to copy every nth (e.g. 5th) message to the copied queue. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is the new feature called “streaming queues” introduced with MQ V. 9.2.3 / 9.3.0. It allows you to let each message which is put to a specific queue duplicated to another queue (the stream queue). To configure it you would need to set two new parameters of your original target queue: STREAMQ( ) to specify the stream queue and STRMQOS( ) to decide for the quality of service (refer to the doc).

Though, to achieve your requirement (“every nth message”), your application which processes the messages of the stream queue would need to only work with the data of every nth message and delete the rest, if you really want to process only a subset of them.

I know this is not a perfect answer to your question, as this solution comes with redundant queuing of messages you don’t want, but I am not aware of any other out-of-the-box solution.